# Multiple if/else condition in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I'm a newbie. I'm using robot framework to implement my test cases. There is a business logic need to check multiple conditions in IF clause like

```
Run Keyword If <condition1>, <condition2>,...
ELSE do something
```

I tried this but It's not working

Single condition -> Work

```
Run Keyword If    'a' == 'a'      log   a
...          ELSE               Log    b
```

Multiple conditions -> Not work

```
Run Keyword IF    'a' == 'a'    and     'b' == 'b'        log   a
...          ELSE               Log    b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire condition needs to be given to the keyword as a single argument, meaning you can't use more than one consecutive space in the expression.

```
Run keyword if  'a' == 'a' and 'b' == 'b'  
...  log  a 
...  ELSE  log  b
```